# how to have 1:m association in Sequelize?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have two models as following:

```
const User     = sequlize.define("user", {...})
const Project  = sequelize.define("project". {...})
```

And I want a 1:M relation between them such that a Project can have multiple users but a User can have a single project.

I tried the following code:

```
User.hasMany(Project, { as: "project" })
```

but hasMany adds foreign key to Project table instead of User table. I know its possible to do it the other way around i.e:

```
Project.hasMany(User, { as: "project" })
```

but if I do that then when I use the following code it throws no association error.

```
User.findOne({ where: { id: "username", password: "password"},
               include: [{ model: Project, as: 'project', required: true }]
            })
```

Comment: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/associations.html - did you set `User.belongsTo()?`

Comment: as far i understood reading the docs `belongsTo()` is used for 1:1 mapping.